# Spark KryoException: Unable to find class: CassandraSQLRow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I`m using Cassandra 2.1.5 (dsc), Spark 1.2.1 with spark-cassandra-connector 1.2.1.

When I run the Spark job (scala script) I get the following error:

> 16/03/08 10:22:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: reduce at
>   JsonRDD.scala:57, took 15.051150 s Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure:  Lost task
>   1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, localhost): com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraS QLRow

I tried to do what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972880/access-cassandra-from-spark-com-esotericsoftware-kryo-kryoexception-unable-to) by using:

```
/home/ubuntu/spark-1.2.1/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/cache/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.2.1.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/ubuntu/.ivy2/cache/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.2.1.jar --class "$class" "$jar"
```

But only get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/datastax/driver/core/ConsistencyLevel
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.WriteConf$.(WriteConf.scala:76)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.WriteConf$.(WriteConf.scala)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.ConfigCheck$.(ConfigCheck.scala:23)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.ConfigCheck$.(ConfigCheck.scala)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$.apply(CassandraConnectorConf.scala:81)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:204)
>           at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.joinWithCassandraTable$default$5(RDDFunctions.scala:127)
>           at co.crowdx.aggregation.SignalIO$.main(SignalIO.scala:92)
>           at co.crowdx.aggregation.SignalIO.main(SignalIO.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel

What could be the issue? 
(I do not want to upgrade spark or cassandra right now)

***EDIT*:**

I tried to run spark shell to see the problem in more simple way:

```
spark-1.2.1/bin/spark-shell --jars /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/cache/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra connector_2.10/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.2.1.jar --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=11.11.11.11
```

And try to run simple commands:

```
> scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext
> import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext
> 
> scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD import
> org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD
> 
> scala> val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc) cc:
> org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext =
> org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext@1c41c05e
> 
> scala> val rdd = cc.sql("select * from listener.scans_daily_imei_partitioned as a, listener.scans_daily_imei_partitioned as b where a.id=b.id")
```

I got the following error:

> rdd: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD =  SchemaRDD[0] at RDD at
>   SchemaRDD.scala:108
>   == Query Plan ==
>   == Physical Plan == com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/datastax/driver/core/ConsistencyLevel

Comment: Could there be multiple versions of the spark datastax connector when you execute your job?

Comment: No, and I explicitly define the path to the connector, so why is it matter?

Comment: It shouldn't, but I'm still wondering if there could be another versioned compiled into your jar which may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue with self compiled spark-cassandra-connector:

```
wget https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/archive/v1.2.1.zip
unzip v1.2.1.zip
cd spark-cassandra-connector-1.2.1
sbt assembly
cp /home/ubuntu/spark-cassandra-connector-1.2.1/spark-cassandra-connector-java/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.2.1.jar spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.2.1-FAT.jar
```

And using the spark as:

```
/home/ubuntu/spark-1.2.1/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /home/ubuntu/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.2.1-FAT.jar --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/ubuntu/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.2.1-FAT.jar --class "$class" "$jar"
```

It worked perfectly.